# Check if Type is a TypeBuilder

Tags: .net, reflection.emit

How can I check if a Type object is a `TypeBuilderInstantiation`?

Basically, I need a method off the Type.

If it's a `TypeBuilderInstantiation`, I need to call `TypeBuilder.GetMethod(...)`, not just `theType.GetMethod(...)` (because it throws a not supported exception).

I can't simply check if theType is `TypeBuilder` because `TypeBuilderInstantiation` inherits directly from Type (not `TypeBuilder`). I can't check directly against `TypeBuilderInstantiation`, because it's internal.

Comment: How do you get hold of that instance? Also TypeBuilder.GetMethods will also throw an exception, if not created. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not compare `Type.Fullname` to what you're expecting for `TypeBuilderInstantiation`?

This smells bad. Can you elaborate on what you're doing that you're mucking around with an internal class?

Comment: I think an instance of TypeBuilderInstantiation is returned when applying type parameters to a TypeBuilder before CreateType has been called, but that's anyones guess.

Comment: That's correct leppie. I'm not mucking around with anything. I am just generating two different types and need one to call a method on the other....but I don't know at runtime if the other is already created or not.

Comment: I've totally had to do this too I just look for `StartsWith("TypeBuilder")` just cus I'll take any less fragility but yeah M$ totally messed things up with an internal type that looks like Type at runtime but acts like a TypeBuilder

Comment: Even worse in mono `TypeBuilderInstantiation` is called `MonoGenericClass`, and also doesn't inherit from TypeBuilder-- go figure.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I feel the approved answer is not very helpful. I've never liked having to compare equality of strings that are provided by the framework, because if they change at some point your application breaks down.

Therefore, having created some more complex systems that build their own types in runtime, let me add my twenty cents in this thread.

A `TypeBuilderInstantiation` is ALWAYS a representation of a generic type, that consists of at least one `TypeBuilder` and then other instances of `Type` (`RuntimeType`, `TypeBuilder` and/or `TypeBuilderInstantiation`). This means that either the generic type definition of the type in question is a `TypeBuilder` or at least one of the generic arguments is a `TypeBuilder`, a `GenericTypeParameterBuilder` or itself a `TypeBuilderInstantiation`. (In case of `GenericTypeParameterBuilder` if it is declared by the generic type itself, it does not count.)

Here's an example how to get instances of `TypeBuilderInstantiation`:

```cs
AssemblyName myAssemblyName = new AssemblyName("MyAssembly");
AssemblyBuilder myAssembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(myAssemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
ModuleBuilder myModule = myAssembly.DefineDynamicModule("MyModule");
TypeBuilder myType = myModule.DefineType("MyType");
//myType (MyType) is TypeBuilder
Type collectionType = typeof(Collection<>).MakeGenericType(myType);
//collectionType (Collection<MyType>) is TypeBuilderInstantiation

TypeBuilder myGenericType = myModule.DefineType("MyGenericType");
GenericTypeParameterBuilder myGenericParam = myGenericType.DefineGenericParameters("T")[0];
//myGenericType (MyGenericType<T>) is TypeBuilder
Type genericType = myType.MakeGenericType(typeof(string));
//genericType (MyGenericType<string>) is TypeBuilderInstantiation

TypeBuilder myOtherGenericType = myModule.DefineType("MyOtherGenericType");
GenericTypeParameterBuilder myOtherGenericParam = myOtherGenericType.DefineGenericParameters("S")[0];
Type otherGenericType = myType.MakeGenericType(myOtherGenericParam);
//otherGenericType (MyGenericType<S>) is TypeBuilderInstantiation
```

Here's a nifty little implementation to check whether a type is a `TypeBuilderInstantiation` or not.

```cs
public static bool IsTypeBuilderInstantiation(Type type)
{
    bool isTypeBuilderInstantiation = false;
    if (type.IsGenericType && !(type is TypeBuilder))
    {
        foreach (var genericTypeArg in type.GetGenericArguments())
        {
            if (isTypeBuilderInstantiation = (
                genericTypeArg is TypeBuilder ||
                genericTypeArg is GenericTypeParameterBuilder ||
                IsTypeBuilderInstantiation(genericTypeArg)))
                break;
        }
        isTypeBuilderInstantiation |= type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() is TypeBuilder;
    }
    return isTypeBuilderInstantiation;
}
```